# update specific rows on table1 with specific values when table1 matches table2 and table 2 row contains a specific level

Tags: sql-server

I've tried to search this but I'm just not getting the proper criteria to get a valid search return.  If I show this, hopefully someone will have an answer.
This is in Sql Server.
Obviously this doesn't work, but here is what I am trying to do.

```
    Update Rating r 
    SET category1 = 1000,
        category2 = 500,
        category3 = 100
    WHERE yearNbr = 2014 AND weekNbr = 0
    AND (SELECT * FROM Team t WHERE r.teamNbr = t.teamNbr and t.tierLevel = 1)

Rating has:
    teamNbr int,
    yearNbr int,
    weekNbr int,
    category1 int,
    category2 int,
    category3 int

Team has:
    teamNbr int,
    teamName VARCHAR(50),
    tierLevel int
```

Basically, I need to Update the Rating table with some specific values into the rows that have a yearNbr of 2014 and a weekNbr of 0, AND I only want to do this for rows that have a tierLevel = 1 on a Team table that matches on teamNbr from both tables. I have 5 different tierLevels and I would just change the category values and the tierLevel in the statement and run it one time for each tierLevel.

Thanks in advance.
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update  r 
SET r.category1 = 1000,
    r.category2 = 500,
    r.category3 = 100
FROM Rating r 
INNER JOIN Team t ON r.teamNbr = t.teamNbr 
                 and t.tierLevel = 1
WHERE r.yearNbr = 2014 AND r.weekNbr = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive this is what you are looking for

```
 Update R  
    SET 
      R.category1 = 1000, R.category2 = 500, R.category3 = 100
    from 
      Rating R
    inner join 
      Team T on T.teamNbr = R.teamNbr    
    and 
      T.tierLevel = 1
    WHERE 
      R.yearNbr = 2014 AND R.weekNbr = 0
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: @M.Ali Thanks to both of you.  It worked great.  Sometimes I try to overthink things.